# Creating features into a layer by using Model Builder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

My friend created a ModelBuilder to place a geographic mean centered point between two selected road lines. Then it calculates the distance between road lines and types its value to a field. After that it calculates the distance by multiplying it with 2 and "boom!" here the distance between two road lines. Then she creates a buffer with this point to create a circle in another layer to show the distance value in it symbologicaly.

She wants to do this process continuously, i mean first she selects two road lines and run the model and she gets what she wants, then she wants to select another two road lines and get a new feature in this layer. But the problem is everytime she runs this code, it creates the feature (and layer) but when you run it again it deletes the previous feature. So everytime you run it, you get only 1 feature. Copying the created feature to another layer didn't work either.

Can you help us to make the model run and store the created features in a layer so she can have a layer full of road distances?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ldun8.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your current output a temporary dataset and then run Append GP tool to add the results into a final output dataset.